# has grown vs is grown

Tags: past-participles, auxiliary-verbs

What is the correct auxiliary in a sentence like this:

> In the last years the number of some-things is/has grown.

?

Comment: Numbers _grow_, and that's a verb, not an adjective, so no _is_. The perfect construction would be _has grown_.

Comment: Sorry, where did I say it is an adjective?

Comment: _Be_ is the auxiliary verb used for predicate adjectives; _grown_ can also be used that way, but not in this sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to denote. I will follow that you really want to denote "the number of some-things" and the available options you gave. The correct answer would be (as John Lawler said):

> In the last years, the number of some-things **has grown**.

This is because the event of *the number* growing is relevant to your (supposed) focus on the present.

---

Here are few other examples for different tenses:

Simple past (Event happened in the past):

> In the last years, fifteen apple trees **were grown**.

Present perfect (Past event with present consequences):

> In the last years, the number of apple trees **has grown** (by four percent).

I suspect this would also be acceptable if you want to focus on the present situation of the apple trees:

> In the last years, fifteen apple trees **have been grown**.

Present continuous perfect (Event started in the past and is still happnening):

> In the last years, the number of apple trees **has been growing**.
>
> In the last years, fifteen apple trees **have been growing**.

Past perfect (Past event with later past consequences):

> In 2000, the number of apple trees **had grown** since 1990.

Comment: `In the last years, fifteen apple trees have been grown.`: this is very strange for me. It is like giving focus that someone has made them grow: isn't it?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi To me, that would be the focus, yes, but not particularly someone. This is passive, and it should focus on the trees, as far as I know.